# PHP copy() converting files into folders

Tags: php, copy

I found this piece of code by Rich Rodecker (http://www.visible-form.com/blog/copy-directory-in-php/). It works fine apart from if there are files in the folder, it converts them into folders.

Here is the PHP snippet from the link above.

```
function copyr($source, $dest){
    // Simple copy for a file
    if (is_file($source)) {
        $c = copy($source, $dest);
        chmod($dest, 0777);
        return $c;
    }
    // Make destination directory
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
        $oldumask = umask(0);
        mkdir($dest, 0777);
        umask($oldumask);
    }
    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == "." || $entry == "..") {
            continue;
        }

        // Deep copy directories
        if ($dest !== "$source/$entry") {
            copyr("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry");
        }
    }
    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return true;
}

copyr("copy","copy2");
```

For example This is the current structure of the site

```
- Root
- - index.php (Code here that runs copy function)
- - copy (DIR)
- - - index.html (Dummy content in file)
```

When I run the index.php it then creates this:

```
- Root
- - index.php (Code here that runs copy function)
- - copy (DIR)
- - - index.html (HTML)

- - copy2 (DIR)
- - - index.html (DIR)
- - - - EMPTY
```

Can anyone see what the problem is and provide a solution? I want to be able to specify a directory and have it back up the entire directory, including sub folders and files.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like putting some output into the isdir/isfile test areas to see what's happening?

Comment: Interesting concept of _It works fine_. I would say it does not work fine

Comment: @RiggsFolly the following 'apart from' conjoins nicely and makes the sentence work, ergo articulating that the rest of the code works, and making the focus this one bug.

Comment: Very articulate. Except the code does not work. Throw it away and copy someone elses hard work.

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.is-file.php):

> Note that is_file() returns false if the parent directory doesn't have
>   +x set for you; this make sense, but other functions such as readdir() don't seem to have this limitation. The end result is that you can
>   loop through a directory's files but is_file() will always fail.

Check permissions for the source directory.